# ng-click does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm programming a single-page web application, mostly using the AngularJS framework, and am encountering a problem while using the ng-click directive.

This directive actually does nothing upon click. The linked method is not called (I can't debug it).

Below the code in question:

template file:

```
<div ng-controller="BonusCtrl as bonusManager">

<!-- [...] --> 
<button style="margin-top: 5px" 
class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"/> Règle de calcul</button>

<!-- [...] -->

</div>
```

controller:

```
idServerApp.controller('BonusCtrl', ['$scope', 'webService', 'math', 'DATERANGE_OPTIONS', function ($scope, webService, math, DATERANGE_OPTIONS) {

$scope.add = function() {
    console.log('foo'); // no call
    var newItem = {
        brandId: undefined,
        days: 0,
        priceMinEVAT: 0,
        bonus: 0
    };
    $scope.rules.push(newItem);
};
```

Do you have any idea of the problem?

---

### Edit 1

I tried to replace bonusManager.add() by add() and BonusCtrl.add().
I then tried to replace $scope by this, or to remove the controllerAs.

[Complete JSFiddle (using some of my services)](http://jsfiddle.net/4nL3js5a/3/)

### Edit 2

Thanks for your answers. I found the solution myself, and it was crappy. 
I forgot a closing div tag in the HTML template, so the controller was not defined.

Comment: You talk about `ng-click` but the attribute you have on the button is `ng-submit` (buttons don't have submit events.)

Comment: Where's the `ng-click`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code a lot in order to debug. The ng-click actually replaces the ng-submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get your code and made an running example with two cases.

First one using **BonusCtrl**

> $scope.add = function () {...}

```
ng-click="add()"
```

And second with **bonusManager**

> this.add = function () {...}

```
ng-click="bonusManager.add()"
```

For me it should works just fine. Please let me know if you have any other issues.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('BonusCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    

$scope.add = function() {
    console.log('Hey you\'ve just invoked add() function!'); // no call
    var newItem = {
        brandId: undefined,
        days: 0,
        priceMinEVAT: 0,
        bonus: 0
    };
  };

  this.add = function () {
    console.log('You can invoke function using \' bonusManager.add()'); // no call
  };

}
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <h1>NG-CLICK EXAMPLE</h1>
    <div ng-controller="BonusCtrl as bonusManager">
    
    <button style="margin-top: 5px" 
    class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"/>add()</button>

  <button style="margin-top: 5px" 
    class="btn btn-success" ng-click="bonusManager.add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"/> bounsManager.add()</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

However you can always use your

Answer (score 1):

Check the working demo: [JSFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/4nL3js5a/1/)

You are using `<div ng-controller="BonusCtrl as bonusManager">`, so call it like:

```
 <button style="margin-top: 5px" class="btn btn-success" 
    ng-submit="bonusManager.add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"/> Règle de calcul</button>
```

In the controller, define `this.add = function() {...` instead of `$scope.add = function() {...`. Because the keyword `as` will call a `new BonusCtrl()` under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work either. I tried with : bonusManager.add(), BonusCtrl.add(), and add().

Comment: Thank you. I tried it to, but didn't understand why doing it. It doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexandreLEBRUN will you please provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `BonusCtrl as bonusManager` then do as follows

Update `bonusManager.add()` in view  and in controller write `this.add` instead of `$scope.add()` .

Otherwise just remove as `bonusManager` from `ng -controller` syntax .it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use $scope than you don't need construction ControllerAs, just use

```
<div ng-controller="BonusCtrl">
```

and submit function  ng-submit="add()"

Or if you want to use ControllerAs, than use "this":

```
<div ng-controller="BonusCtrl as bonusManager">
ng-submit="BonusCtrl.add()"
```

But in your controller have to be "this" instead of $scope:
`

> this.add = function() {

`

Try it.